# Sending an email with php from a html page

Tags: php, html, forms, submit

I am trying to configure this boostrap template: [Github link](https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-business-casual/)

I do not have a datebase to use and on the Github page it says:

> "Your must enter your database information and your email in
>   form-handler.php - if you don't have a database, that's fine. Edit
>   contact.html to direct the form to form-handler-nodb.php and emails
>   will be sent with no database writes."

I do not understand exactly what it means to "direct the form to form-handler-nodb.php". I have tried to change the form attributes in contact.html to be `<form action="/form-handler-nodb.php" method="post" role="form">` , but that just results in form-handler-nodb.php being downloaded when I hit the submit button.

My question is then what do I need to change in contact.html to be able to submit the email that is in the form on the page?

This is driving me insane! Thank you for your help.

Comment: The file is downloaded because PHP is probably not running on your server.

Comment: I feel like an idiot now. Will try to get this on a server and then will post an update. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As Capsule mentioned in the comments I was not running a server when I was testing it locally. By uploading the contact.html to my server I started seeing this working.

As a side note, there was also a mistake in the form-handler-nodb.php file where `"\nEmail: " . $email;` needed to be changed to `"\nEmail: " . $message` to actually have the inputed email message submitted.

Thank you for the help Capsule!